# Why are there no solid-state blue lasers?

Tags: laser

Why are there no viable solid state gain media that directly lase in the visible spectrum? With the exception of ruby used in the first laser (red), all of the bulk gain materials like Nd:YAG and related have transitions between 900 and 1500nm.

What are the fundamental physical reasons that gain materials with transitions below 600nm have not been discovered or invented? With the inefficiencies of frequency doubled solid state lasers surely there is motivation to do so.

Note that I am not counting diode lasers, like GaN, which have many restrictions of geometry and power output compared with a bulk crystal like YAG.

Comment: [This](https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-012583961-7/50006-5) is a sample chapter of a book for sale. It discusses green frequency doubled Nd:YAG lasers. Probably not the answer you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but I am specifically looking for information about lasers that directly emit in the blue-green spectrum without frequency doubling.

Comment: Pr+ doped materials are used for RGB lasers. However they use part of the blue pump as the B part. I do not think my comment here is good enough to be elligble for an answer, but lasers require specific characteristics of the medium's energy levels, and separations of energy in the VIS are hard to come by. Most visible and UV lasers are gas lasers due to that case where you have atomic transitions rather than bulk/crystalline transitions. Of course in bulk, everything is packed much closer, so energy structure is also more compact.

Comment: @JoséAndrade I am not familiar with RGB lasers using Pr+, can you give me a reference? You should definitely throw up and Answer, I think you are on to something above. It may not be the full story I am looking for but it should net you some rep points.

Comment: @Mike, sorry, but I do not feel confident enough that my answer would be physically correct as this is not my main field of research and my knowledge in this field is limited. But through the following link, you should find an open access paper on praseodymium doped fluorides (first image shows emission lines). [Paper here](https://www.osapublishing.org/oe/fulltext.cfm?uri=oe-15-8-5172&id=132263)

Comment: (just a parentheses, I would gladly do laser testing of new materials, as I did before, I understand what we want from the materials, and I can build lasers, but I have zero clue on how to engineer crystals/ceramics/glasses to achieve those properties, my knowledge there is very very, but very basic)

Answer (score 3):

Solid state blue lasers exist. Moreover, they exist for a while and there is even a [dedicated Wkipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_laser#Semiconductor_lasers) (with hopefully helpful references).

The difficulty in creating solid state blue lasers, depends on what type of laser we are talking about.

- *Semiconductor lasers* require material that can be both made conducting by doping and has a sufficiently large bandgap - the more studied materials have bandgaps close to infrared spectrum, which si why the first semiconductor lasers were working in this range, gradually evolving towards higher frequencies as better materials were mastered.
- Lasers based on rare earth elements require ions with the corresponding transition incorporated into solid state matrix. So it is again the question of creating a coresponding material, which was not readily available. Note that this is in a sense a step in the direction of gas lasers, exploting the transitions between the levels of isolated itoms, rather than interband transitions, which are truly a hallmark of the solid state.
- Finally, another successful path is using *quantum dots* - i.e., artificially created atoms, where the spacing between levels is well controlled and can be made sufficiently large. As their integrated into a crystal as its part, pumpng can be achieved by either electrical or optical means.

**Update**
As discussed in the comments, many high frequency transitions are easily available in gas and die lasers, but not in the solid state lasers, which are confined to read and infra-red spectrum. Indeed, in a crystal it is difficult to have a metastable state that has energy higher than the bandgap: the continuous spectrum in the bands means that there are many possibilities for non-radiative relaxation (e.g., many processes mediated via Coulomb and phonon interactions). This is not the case with atoms/molecules, where a high energy level can be just as long-living as a lower one.

One could further argue that the valence and the conductance bands of a crystal are essentially formed from the higherst occupied and the lowest unoccupied orbitals of the constituting atoms, thus limiting the optical emission from semiconductor crystals to this interval. This is also the reason for the use of the rare earth elements in solid state lasers, since their f-shell remains relatively uncoupled from the conduction and valence bands, formed from s and p orbitals. These material constraints do not exist for the gas lasers, whose working environment is inert gases that could not be integrated into a solid state matrix.

Comment: Please note that my question is about gain materials that directly emit in the blue-green spectrum and specifically excludes semiconductor lasers and frequency doubling does not provide gain at the output wavelength. Your 2nd and 3rd points are going in the right direction. This question aims to understand why the necessary interband transitions are plentiful for IR lasers but not for blue.

Comment: @Mike this is why I did need to include my first point: this is the way the nature is. Visible spectrum is determined by the materials that are widespread in the nature. Once you are at the edge of the visible spectrum; whether blue or terahertz, there are less materials available.

Comment: *I mean *optical spectrum* - obviously not all of it is visible.

Comment: I am not following your argument here. We see plenty of evidence in nature for materials that absorb and emit across the visible spectrum. Why then are the vast majority of available laser transitions in the near-IR. There is something in atomic physics that I am missing here.

Comment: In solid state it is difficult to have a metastable state that has energy higher than the bandgap, because the continuous spectrum in the bands means that there are many possibilities for non-radiative relaxation. This is not the case with atoms, where a high energy level can be just as long-living as a lower one.

Comment: I think you are getting much closer to the heart of the matter. I would like to understand these constraints on what energy levels and transitions are possible.

Comment: @Mike I expanded the answer a bit more on the subject of the material constraints, but I couldn't be more specific than that: I did my masters in laser phsyics, but since then I have worked in a different field. I hope it helps.